# Websocket Error with Chrome Browser Websocket PluginExtension

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I wanted to try out some Websocket endpoint for my application and I downloaded the Chrome extension, but when I tried it, I ran into the following error as can be seen from the screenshot below:

[image]

Any ideas as to how I could get it fixed?